# align-items/content does not work on a container in IE10/11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Given the following code:

```css
.FlexContainer {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.FlexItem {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* set default for IE10 */
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem">
    HELLO WORLD
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the items to be aligned along the bottom of the container:
[image]

However in IE10 and 11 it doesn't seem to respect it
[image]

Is this a bug of IE or I am doing something wrong here,Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: IE 10 & 11 have a lot of issues with flex

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `min-height`. In IE11 if the **height** is set this works as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items

Comment: any chance for an answer with example?